# What is the differance?

Tags: prepositions

I just fell it is hard to know what it should be (From or Since)
e.g: I am not suprised that you didnot eat anything (from-since)the morning.

Comment: Please, fix the spelling in the title, and the spaces, as an act of courtesy to users. Nowadays, anyone can download a spell-checker and an English dictionary on their browser.

Comment: Hi,  I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Since** - will be used when we are talking about a time in the past until now.

```
Eg. They have been friends since childhood
```

**From**  - used to indicate a specified place or time as a starting point.

```
Eg. I walked home from the station
```

**(Additional) For** - to use when we talk about the length of time (like a day, hours)

```
(Combined Eg). I walked home from the station for 1 hours since it was 4 o'clock.
```

---

So to your question "I am not surprised that you didn't eat anything (from-since)the morning."

> since - would be the answer to it.

Comment: That meaning of *since* in your combined example is different.   In that context, *since* = *because*.    It is also worth noting the some of the confusion can come from the fact the the expression *from (point in time)*  \[and\] ***on*** is roughly equivalent to *since* in your first sense.   As in, *He hasn't been in the office from noontime on* = *He hasn't been in the office since noontime*.

Comment: For the combined eg, I want to be understood that now it is not 4 o'clock, but "I" walked since 4 o'clock and not arrived yet. I also don't understand why "since = because" in that context. I guess there's no reasoning!?